# Why aren't pictures taken on my new DSLR camera showing up when I put the SD card in my computer?

Tags: dslr, sdcard, file-transfer

I have previously used a point and shoot camera but have a new DSLR camera. I used my old SD card in my new camera, and while I can see all the pictures when my SD card is in the camera, none of the new DSLR pictures  are showing up on my computer. What is wrong?

Comment: What are you using to see the photos? You are probably in the wrong directory or shooting RAW. Make sure you try again with the camera set to JPEG, that way it will produce actual images.

Comment: What operating system and software are you using to try to view the images?

Comment: The Windows photo viewer. Shooting in RAW format. Thanks guys, and I just found Mac has native RAW support.

Comment: Just to check my understanding: is it the case that the files themselves are showing up on the SD card, but the photo viewer isn't showing them?

Comment: Keep in mind that shooting in RAW is actually better, you get much better quality and more editing options. Just the standard viewers can't handle RAWS.

Comment: Just in case your camera is using 2 SD cards (you don't say which DSLR you're using) try taking a look at the other one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Photo Viewer does not support RAW images by default. You need to download the Microsoft Camera Codec Pack here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26829

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your SD card is properly connected to your computer. Use a card reader or insert the SD card directly to the SD card slot. You can also try to reinstall the device driver. For doing that, you need to go to “device manager” option. Thereafter, double click on the disk drives option. Right click on the removable drive and click uninstall. You can now restart your computer and reconnect SD card to see the results.

Answer (score -2):

Try formatting your card to exFat. This worked for me

Comment: How does this help the OP view the images they already took, that are on the card? Formatting the card will cause the photos to be lost.